# Can items in a css-grid-area flow to multiple rows

Tags: css, css-grid

**The problem**

As you can see in the first image we got an cssgrid where all items are distributed nicely across all rows and are positioned in the most optimal position.

Starting point:

[image: Starting point]

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(24px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.item {
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.aa {
  background-color: red;
}

.bb {
  background-color: green;
}

.cc {
  background-color: blue;
}

.dd {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item aa" style="grid-column: 3 / span 1"></div>
  <div class="item bb" style="grid-column: 5 / span 1"></div>
  <div class="item cc" style="grid-column: 7 / span 1"></div>
  <div class="item cc" style="grid-column: 9 / span 1"></div>
  <div class="item bb" style="grid-column: 2 / span 4"></div>
  <div class="item dd" style="grid-column: 7 / span 3"></div>
  <div class="item bb" style="grid-column: 2 / span 8"></div>
  <div class="item bb" style="grid-column: 1 / span 6"></div>
  <div class="item bb" style="grid-column: 9 / span 3"></div>
  <div class="item dd" style="grid-column: 1 / span 11"></div>
</div>
```

Some of these items share the same color, so I'm looking for a way to group them together so it will be easier to find the right one. After applying a `grid-template-area` to the container and the corresponding `grid-area` to the items, they all clamped together on one row as seen in the second image.

After applying grid areas:

[image: After applying grid areas]

```css
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(24px, 1fr));
      grid-auto-flow: column;
      grid-template-areas: 
        'bb'
        'aa'
        'cc'
        'dd';
    }

    .item {
      height: 24px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: 8px 0;
    }

    .aa {
      background-color: red;
    }

    .bb {
      background-color: green;
    }

    .cc {
      background-color: blue;
    }

    .dd {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item aa" style="grid-area: aa / 3 / aa / span 1"></div>
  <div class="item bb" style="grid-area: bb / 5 / cc / span 1"></div>
  <div class="item cc" style="grid-area: cc / 7 / cc / span 1"></div>
  <div class="item cc" style="grid-area: cc / 9 / cc / span 1"></div>
  <div class="item bb" style="grid-area: bb / 2 / bb / span 4"></div>
  <div class="item dd" style="grid-area: dd / 7 / dd / span 3"></div>
  <div class="item bb" style="grid-area: bb / 2 / bb / span 8"></div>
  <div class="item bb" style="grid-area: bb / 1 / bb / span 6"></div>
  <div class="item bb" style="grid-area: bb / 9 / bb / span 3"></div>
  <div class="item dd" style="grid-area: dd / 1 / dd / span 11"></div>
</div>
```

**The solution I'm looking for**

As seen in the third image I'm looking for a way to group items together, but still use cssgrid to position the items in the most optimal way.

What I need:

[image: What I need]

**Related question**
How does the performance of an `css-grid` hold up vs position `absolute` `top`/`left`?